# Recurrence Relation Initial Condition Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have this problem:

> Solve the recurrence
> \begin{cases}
> x(n) = x(n/2) + n & \text{for } n > 1, \\ 
> x(1) = 1 & 
> \end{cases}
> for $n = 2^k$.

The idea is to take the recurrence relation of $A(2^k)$, then swap it out for $n$ at the end. I've gotten to the point in my problem where I have found the common pattern, which is
$$
A(2^{k-i}) + 2^{k-i} + 2^{k-(i-1)} + 2^{k-(i-2)}, 
$$
etc. Now, I'm unsure how to finish off this problem using the initial condition. I'm just not sure where to begin with the fact that $x(1) = 1$. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the recurrence relation to generate the first few terms in the sequence:
$$
x(2) = x(1) + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3, 
$$
and similarly,
$$
x(4) = x(2) + 4 = 3 + 4 = 7, 
$$
and
$$
x(8) = x(4) + 8 = 7 + 8 = 15. 
$$
Here are these values collected in a table.
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
k & 2^k & x(2^k) \\
\hline 
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 7 \\
3 & 8 & 15
\end{array}

Hopefully, you can see the pattern:

> $$ x(2^k) = 2^{k+1} - 1, $$

which can be proved by induction on $k$.

Answer (score 0):

After substitution , the recurrence reads

$$
x(2^k) = x(2^{k-1})+2^k
$$

then calling $s(k) = x(2^k)$ the sequence can be recast as

$$
s(k) = s(k-1)+ 2^k
$$

and now it is obvious that

$$
s(k) = c_0 + \sum_{j=0}^{j=k}2^j
$$

and now as $x(1) = x(2^0) = s(0) = 1$ we have

$$
s(0) = c_0 + 1 = 1\Rightarrow c_0 = 0
$$

and the final solution is

$$
x(2^k) = s(k) = \sum_{j=0}^{j=k}2^j = \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2-1} = 2n-1=x(n)
$$